# Date formatting - adding days to date

Tags: c++, algorithm, date

I have date in this format for example :

```
12.2.2015
```

I have to add days to that date. For example i have to add to that date + 1000 days so the output will not be `12 . 2 . 2015`  but `14 . 3 . 2018 ( it's not accurate i did not calculate it).` Is there any effective algorithm for this problem or do i have to loop it and make lots of conditions about leap year etc?

Comment: Is this a homework task? Almost identical question (even identical tags) asked almost at the same time as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372774/date-and-time-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have

```
int year = 2015;
int month = 2;
int day = 12;
int offset = 1000;
```

You can utilize `<ctime>` [functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) like `mktime` and `localtime` and belief that every day has 86400 seconds to do what you need. Something like this.

```
#include <ctime>

struct tm orig_date;
orig_date->tm_sec = 0;
orig_date->tm_min = 0;
orig_date->tm_hour = 12; /* midday, so we make space for non-86400 errors */
orig_date->tm_mday = day;
orig_date->tm_mon = month - 1; /* uses 0-11 range */
orig_date->tm_year = year;
orig_date->tm_isdst = 0;

time_t utc = mktime(&orig_date);

utc += (offset * 86400);

struct tm *new_date;

new_date = localtime(&utc);

printf("Old date: %d. %d. %d\n", orig_date.tm_mday, orig_date.tm_mon, orig_date.tm_year);
printf("New date: %d. %d. %d\n", new_date->tm_mday, new_date->tm_mon, new_date->tm_year);
```

The code will produce following *(which I checked to be correct)*:

```
Old date: 12. 1. 2015
New date: 8. 10. 2017
```